# Creating file based on free space available on disk powershell

Tags: powershell

I have to create alert in SNOW if disk usage more than 85%.

I did the code which is calculating the 85% and giving me value (e.g. 57GB)

Now I need to divide this 57GB into number to logical drives and create text file on each drive base on it's free space

[image]

```
# Get information about all logical drives
$drives = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 3 -and $_.DeviceID -ne "S:"}

# Count the total number of logical drives
$totalDrives = $drives.Count

if ($totalDrives -gt 0) {
    # Calculate the size for each drive
    $sizePerDrive = [math]::Round($File_size_for_warning / $totalDrives)

    # Create blank text files of calculated size on each drive
    foreach ($drive in $drives) {
        $driveLetter = $drive.DeviceID
        $filePath = "$driveLetter\TestFile.txt"

        # Create a blank text file with the computed size
        $null = New-Item -Path $filePath -ItemType File -Value (" " * $sizePerDrive)
        
        Write-Host "Created $sizePerDrive GB file on $driveLetter"
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "No logical drives found."
}
```

the above code is excluding SWAP and on rest of 8 drives creating files of 7.6GB each. but as you can see few drives are having less than 2-4GB space.

Please let me know how can I divide the amount in this senario.

**Note: Have to create file in each drive as per requirement**

Comment: Wouldn't your alerting threshold be _per disk_? :) You should probably be calculating the free space for each disk separately

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Yes. I missed that. I am reworking now. thanks.